# Add code to "with" function on vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim numFilas As Long

numFilas = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = numFilas To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("h:h"), Cells(i, 8)) > 1 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

I want to add it to the following  code for to modify the other sheet ("MOV MERCADERIA"). How do I do that?

```
With Sheets("MOV MERCADERIA")
    For a = 11 To Range("a40").End(xlUp).Row
        fila = .Range("a1:a65536").Find("").Row
        .Cells(fila, 1) = [d7]                   'remito
        .Cells(fila, 2) = CDate([D6])            'fecha
        .Cells(fila, 3) = [D8]                   'cod proveedor
        .Cells(fila, 4) = [E8]                   'proveedor
        .Cells(fila, 5) = [D9]                   'CODIGO responsable
        .Cells(fila, 6) = [K8]                   'tipo
        For b = 0 To 17
            If Cells(a, b + 1) <> "" Then
                col = .Cells(fila, 16).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                .Cells(fila, col) = Cells(a, b + 1)
            End If
        Next b
        .Cells(fila, 26) = [N44]
    Next a
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to insert the code somewhere after `With Sheets("MOV MERCADERIA")`and before the `End With` and replace `Cells` with `.Cells`, `range` with `.range`, and `rows` with `.rows`

Like so:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim numFilas As Long

With Sheets("MOV MERCADERIA")

    numFilas = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = numFilas To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("h:h"), .Cells(i, 8)) > 1 Then
           .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

Now the code will act on sheet `MOV MERCADERIA`

Comment: Great to hear that!

Comment: Any user can mark an answer to his question as accepted. I don't mean the upvote button, I mean this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png